# Asignar un objeto a un Estado, useState React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

1 en cartData se tienen los productos de un carrito de compras, es un array de ahi requiero solo
quantity, _id y timestamp + la propiedad del id y se asigna al estado orderItems

2 En el useEffect si el estado orderItems existe, a la función orderProductList le envio  esa
lista de productos q esta en order items

3 En la constante setproductsToOrder recibo una promesa que al resolverla me regresa un objeto con
unas propiedades

4 quiero asignar ese res que me trae la función a un estado que llamé newOrder, pero siempre me
envia un objeto vació.

5 No si el problema es que está dentro de un async await,s ie s así como lo puedo corregir,
gracias por la ayuda

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { menuOptions } from '../../redux/actions/checkOutActions';
import {orderInformation, orderProductList} from '../../utils/services/orderServices';
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";
import {allUserOrders} from '../../redux/actions/orderActions';



const Summarizing = ({menuOptions, userData, cartData, orderData, allUserOrders}) => {


 const { addToast } = useToasts();  

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({});
  const [orderItems, setOrderItems] = useState({});
  const [newOrder, setNewOrder] = useState({});

 

  const handleClick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      setSelectedOption({
        finishShopping: false,
        myOrders: true
      })
  }

  const orderProducts = (cartData) => {
    const singleItem = cartData.map((item)=>{
        return {
            quantity: item.quantity,
            _id: item.id,
            timestamp: item.timestamp
        }
    })
    setOrderItems({
        products: singleItem,
        storeId: "1234"
    });
  }


  //informacion del usuario que crea la orden
  useState(()=>{
    orderInformation(orderData)
  },[orderData])




useEffect(()=>{
    if(Object.entries(orderItems).length > 0){

        const setproductsToOrder = orderProductList(orderItems);
          const orderStatus = async () => {

            const res = await setproductsToOrder;

            if(res.status === 200){
                setNewOrder(res) // ======> Error al enviar No envia nada
                addToast("Se ha creado una nueva orden", {
                    appearance: "success",
                    autoDismiss: true
                    })
            }else{
                addToast("No se ha podido crear la orden", {
                appearance: "error",
                autoDismiss: true
                })
            }
          }
          orderStatus();
      }
},[addToast, orderItems])


  useEffect(()=>{
    menuOptions(selectedOption)
  },[selectedOption, menuOptions])


   const orderPrice = cartData.reduce((acc, item)=>{
        return acc = acc + item.price*item.quantity
    },0)


  return (
        <div className="summarizing shadow-sm p-4 col-12 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between mb-5">
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-6 p-4 p-3 mb-3 mb-lg-0 summarizinInfo">
                <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                    <h5 className="font-weight-bold">Información general</h5>
                </div>
                <p>{userData.firstName} {userData.lastName}</p>
                <p>{userData.email}</p>
                <p className="d-flex align-items-center m-0">
                    <h5 className="font-weight-bold m-0 pr-2">Dirección de envío: </h5>
                    {orderData.address}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-6 pr-0 pl-0 pl-lg-4">
                <div className="col-12 p-4  mb-3 summarizinInfo">
                    <h5 className="font-weight-bold">Método de pago</h5>
                    <p>Efectivo</p>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 p-4 summarizinInfo shadow-sm">
                    <h5 className="font-weight-bold">Valor a pagar</h5>
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <p className="m-0">Subtotal</p>
                        <p className="m-0">{ orderPrice &&  orderPrice}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <p className="m-0">Impuestos</p>
                        <p className="m-0">0</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <p className="m-0 font-weight-bold">Total</p>
                        <p className="m-0">{ orderPrice &&  orderPrice}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-end col-12 p-0 mt-3">
            {/* onClick={handleClick}  */}
                <button
                 onClick={(e)=>{
                    handleClick(e);
                    orderProducts(cartData)
                 }}
                 className="border-0 ">
                 FINALIZAR COMPRA
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("STATE CART DATA DESDE SUMARIZING ", state);
    return {
        userData: state.userData.user,
        cartData: state.cartData,
        orderData: state.orderData
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        menuOptions: (selectedOption)=> {
            dispatch(menuOptions(selectedOption))
        },
        allUserOrders: (userOrders)=> {
            dispatch(allUserOrders(userOrders))
        }
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Summarizing)
```